# $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with one and only one limit point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that no three points in $S$ are collinear

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Question as in the title, but here it is re-typed just in case not all of the title is visible on your screen (you're welcome):

I am interested if there is a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with one and only one limit point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that no three points in $S$ are collinear. I also require the limit point of $S$ to not be a member of the set $S$.

Either proof by construction or a less direct proof are both adequate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about $S = \{(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n^2}) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$? This set has only one limit point $(0, 0)$ and no three points in $S$ are collinear.