# An extension of a question about no 3 points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ being collinear

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am interested to see if we can use any of the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514888/set-s-subset-mathbbr2-with-one-and-only-one-limit-point-in-mathbbr2/514899?noredirect=1#514899) - or other methods - to answer the following question(s):

Does there exist a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ whose set of limit points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ contains the line $[0,1] =$ {$(x,0):  0 \le x \le 1$} such that no 3 points in S are collinear?

Update: I've deleted a silly follow-on question from the OP to simplify things for readers.

Comment: The answer to your first question is of course "no": $S\subset [0,1]$ and it must contain an infinite number of points. In the second case let $S$ be that circle.

Comment: And for the second one the answer is yes-the circle itself has no three points collinear.

Comment: njguliyev - why must S be a subset of [0,1]?

And Ross yes you are right about the second question of course

Comment: For the first question, you can get a set $S$ whose set of *limit points* is $[0,1]$, and such that no $3$ points in $S$ are collinear.

Comment: Do you mean for the set of *limit points* of $S$ to be the line segment, rather than the closure?

Comment: Well actually what I meant to write was that [0,1] is a subset of the closure of S but it amounts to the same thing

Comment: @AdamRubinson, because when I wrote that comment your question was about "closure", not "set of limit points".

Comment: Yes you are right and my OP was wrong before and I just corrected it thanks to your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To produce our set $S$, we "fly over" the interval $[0,1]$ again and again from left to right.  At the $n$-th stage, we add points with $x$-coordinates $\frac{k}{2^n}$, where $k$ ranges over the odd numbers from $0$ to $2^n$. The $y$-coordinates of the points added during the $n$-th stage are positive and have absolute value $\lt \frac{1}{2^n}$.

At any time, we have only chosen a finite number of points, which determine a finite number of lines. So when we are choosing the $y$-coordinate of the point in $S$ corresponding to $x$-coordinate $\frac{k}{2^n}$, only finitely many points need to be avoided.

Take any real $r$ in the interval $[0,1]$. For any $n$, there is a point of our set whose $x$-coordinate differs from $r$ by at most $\frac{1}{2^n}$, and therefore whose distance from the point $(r,0)$ is positive and $\lt \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}$. So there is a sequence of points in $S$ with limit $(r,0)$.

Comment: Very clear example. Thanks for you answer Andre.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Andre, on second passing, it looks to me like you've only proven that (a) the collinearity condition holds for every finite case. I am not convinced that you have proven it holds for the infinite case. However, let me try to rectify this. You have proven (a) and also (b) the construction gives us an infinite sequence S whose set of limit points is [0,1]. It remains to be shown that the collinearity condition holds for S. Suppose it doesn't.

Comment: Then there is a "minimal criminal" a_n in S such that a_n is the member of a triple which lies in a straight line and the other two points in the triple are before it in the sequence. But this contradicts the fact that collinearity works for the finite case (Up to a_n)

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Yes, if we get collinearity, there must have been collinearity at some stage. Works like linear dependence.

Answer (score 3):

The set $Q=\mathbb Q\cap(0,1)$ is a countable dense subset of $[0,1]$. Enumerate $Q=\{q_1,q_2,\ldots\}$, i.e. choose a bijection $q:\mathbb N\to Q$.  Now, let $$S=\{(q_n,\pi^{-n})|\;n\in \mathbb N\}.$$ No three points in $S$ are collinear, since this would mean $$(q_n,\pi^{-n})-(q_m,\pi^{-m})=\lambda((q_m,\pi^{-m})-(q_k,\pi^{-k}))$$ for some distinct natural numbers $n,m,k$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb R$. Comparing the first components, we get that $\lambda$ must be rational. Using this fact and comparing the second components, we obtain a nonzero polynomial with rational coefficients, that has $\pi$ as a zero. This contradicts the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental.

Closure of $S$ contains $[0,1]\times\{0\}$: choose an arbitrary open ball (in the $\infty$-norm for simplicity) centered at some $(x,0)$ where $x\in[0,1]$ with some (arbitrary) radius $r>0$. Then this ball must contain infinitely many points of $Q\times\{0\}$, since $Q$ is dense in $[0,1]$, so it contains $q_n$ with arbitrarily big $n$. Choose $n$ so that $\pi^{-n}<r$. Then $(q_n,\pi^{-n})$ lies inside the ball. This shows that for each $(x,0)\in[0,1]\times\{0\}$ there are points of $S$ arbitrarily close to $(x,0)$, thus proving the claim.

Comment: The way you define it, you only have one point at each $x$ value.  The approach will work, but you need infinitely many at each $x$ value while avoiding the use of any $y$ value (the $\pi^{-n}$s more than twice.  This can be done.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I have reworded the last paragraph a bit. Is it better now?

Comment: The problem is the reuse of $n$ in $(q_n,\pi^{-n})$, so you associate one given power of $\pi$ with each rational.  But then you need not to use a given power of $\pi$ more than twice or there will be a horizontal line with three points on it.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I'm still not sure what you mean ... I assumed $n\mapsto q_n$ is a bijection, i.e., I do indeed use each $n$ only once. I assign a unique natural number $n$ to each rational in $(0,1)$, so the powers of $\pi$ are also distinct.

Comment: For $q_n$ you need an infinite set of points $(q_n,\pi^{-m})$ to have enough to make $(q_n,0)$ a limit point.  It looks to me like you only have one point in the set with $x$ coordinate $q_n$, specifically $(q_n,\pi^{-n})$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Sorry for bothering you again, but what about $(\frac1n,\frac1n)$? This has $(0,0)$ as a limit point and yet there is only a single point for each $x$ and $y$ coordinate. In my case, it is sufficient to have a subsequence $(q_{m_k},\pi^{-m_k})$ that converges to $(q_n,0)$. As far as I can see, my argument shows that it is always possible to choose such a subsequence. (Note that the second coordinate always converges to $0$, and furthermore, there are enough rationals in the vicinity of $q_n$ (or any other $x\in[0,1]$) to also make the first coordinate converge appropriately.)

Comment: A good point.  I'll have to think on it a bit, but I see how it could work.  A good example why limit points are hard.

Comment: I finally realized I was wrapped around the axle thinking we were trying to make the limit points $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$, not all of $[0,1]$, and turning that into needing a vertical series at each $q_n$.  Sorry for putting you through all this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. Think of it like this, fisrt enumerate every rational in [0, 1] $q _ {0}, q_{1},q_{2}$... now proceed with consecutive choices, take $a_{0} = (q_0, 1)$ and $a_{n} = (q_n,y)$ whith y chosen so that it wont be collinear with any other couple of point and $|y|\le 2^{-n}$ it is alway possible becouse in the set $\{(q_0,t):0\lt t\le 2^{-n}\}$ only a finite number of points are subtracted for the non collinear request, this way for every (x,0) on your segment and for every $r \gt 0$ the ball centered on x whit radius r contain infinite point because it containt infinite rational point $(q_k, y_k)$ with k big enought so that $2^{-k} \lt r/4$ and $|x-q_k| \lt r/4$ thus in the ball.
actually you can manually choose the value of $y_k$, indeed you can take $y_k = sqrt(p_{k}/p_ {k}+1) $ this because all the $y_k$ are independent on **R** seen as vectorial space on **Q**; or also $y_k = \pi^{-k}$ for the same reason.
Note that every point with rational x-coordinate on the line generated by $(q_k,y_k)$ and $(q_j,y_j)$ are of the form $((1-a)*q_k + a*q_j),(1-a)*y_k + a*y_k)$ for some rational $a$.